# Matrix problem that finds the required matrix that when summed up to get a matrix of prime numbers

Tags: python, matrix, numbers

so I've written a code in Python that counts how many times I should add 1 to every element in a n*m matrix to get all of them to be prime. Here is the code:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n == 1 or n == 0 or n < 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int((n ** 0.5)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

n, m = map(int, input().split())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])

mtxsum = [[0] * m] * n

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        init = l[i][j]
        if not isPrime(l[i][j]):
            while isPrime(l[i][j]) != True:
                if l[i][j] == 1:
                    l[i][j] += 1
                elif l[i][j] % 2 == 0:
                    l[i][j] += 1
                else:
                    l[i][j] += 2
        mtxsum[i][j] = (l[i][j] - init)
        print(mtxsum[i][j])
        print(mtxsum)
```

Now, I get confused at this part:

```
mtxsum[i][j] = (l[i][j] - init)
        print(mtxsum[i][j])
        print(mtxsum)
```

where instead of changing for example only the element at the position [0][0], the elements at the positions [1][0], [2][0], ... are being changed as well, getting at the end the matrix:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

but I should get:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

What am I missing/doing wrong? Note that at the start, the matrix of sum is a matrix On*m (only with 0 elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a matrix like `mtxsum = [[0] * m] * n`, every element in matrix changes if you try to change any single element. That is why every element in matrix "mtxsum" overrides to "1".
So create matrix manually with iterations.

```
mtxsum = []
for i in range(n):
   temp = []
   for j in range(m):
      temp.append(0)
   mtxsum.append(temp)
```

Now you are good to go.